# When do you create unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd

Before writing a feature?
After writing a feature?
AFter writing several features just before reaching a milestone?

My devs argue that they do number 3 for the 1st mileston because they would refactor and optimize during the initial development and that the unit test they create can be invalid after refactoring the codes.

Comment: People can (and have) argued for hours over testing methodologies. This question may not be a good fit for [so].

Comment: You have labelled this question TDD, which means writing the tests first.

Comment: @metacubed Nonsense. It is well defined how the testing is done in TDD. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Comment: @BЈовић Do read my comment carefully. I'm talking about testing methodologies. The [tdd] tag seems to be a misnomer given the actual content of the question. It asks about the best time/schedule for writing unit tests, while accounting for changes like refactoring, optimization, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically unit test refers to the testing of a small piece of code that does something specific. In my experience at least, the lowest granularity would be a function, but you can have multiple unit tests for that function to exercise different input arguments and paths through that function.

Given this background, functions would be defined clearly at the detailed design stage, even before implementation starts. It therefore makes sense to write unit tests as soon as you have completed writing the function.

When refactoring happens, two scenarios arise:

1. Refactor the internals of the function: unit tests are unlikely to
   be affected.
2. Refactor at design level: this indicates that detailed
   design had some flaws but a good design team will ensure that
   redesign is minimal. In this case, parts of code have to refactored
   and hence unit tests have to be refactored as well. Old unit test
   code could be reused in parts.

Either way, it is best to do unit testing along with implementation. Problems are caught out early in the implementation cycle. Another thought: what triggers refactoring? Possibly bad design. In some cases, you might discover the need to refactor when doing unit testing. Ultimately, unit testing is meant to help developers and give confidence in their own code. It should not be seen as redundant effort to pacify the project manager.

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the [tdd](/questions/tagged/tdd) tag, it means that you are practicing test driven development. In that case, the unit tests are written first, before any code.

Having requirements, and knowing what to do, it is fairly simple to write unit tests first. Of course, initially the compilation is going to fail, but that is treated in the same manner as broken unit tests.

> My devs argue that they do number 3 for the 1st mileston because they would refactor and optimize during the initial development and that the unit test they create can be invalid after refactoring the codes.

That is a nonsense. It is not possible to refactor the code, without having tests (unit, integration, etc) in place. How else would you validate that the code is doing the same thing?